# combing jquery mobile with cordova on pageinit

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure this. I'm loading an external html page into my app. I have a pageinit function that fills the page with some data. I would also like to pull in the phone's geolocation with this but i need to check for device ready to use cordova. How do i make sure that the function will get fired when cordova is ready?

I have the following, but i get an alert "Code: 2, Message: Failed to start Geolocation service" every time.

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {

    $('#latnlng').html(position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude );
};

function onFailure(error){
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

jq( document ).delegate("#singleCompany", "pageinit", function() {
    retrieveCompany("527378C0D3465729A2F0B8C063396C5D");

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onFailure);
});
```

I think i need to combine it with the following but am unsure how

```
document.addEvenListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onFailure);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `navigator.geolocation...` code from the `pageinit` event handler and run it inside the `deviceready` event handler. The geo-location API that Cordova exposes won't be available until the `deviceready` event fires.

For Example:

```
jq( document ).delegate("#singleCompany", "pageinit", function() {
    retrieveCompany("527378C0D3465729A2F0B8C063396C5D");
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onFailure);
}
```

**UPDATE**

To run the geo-location code for only a single page (that is not the starting page) you can set a flag to determine whether the `deviceready` event has fired.

For Example:

```
var isDeviceReady = false;
function onDeviceReady(){
    isDeviceReady = true;
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

jq( document ).delegate("#singleCompany", "pageinit", function() {
    retrieveCompany("527378C0D3465729A2F0B8C063396C5D");

    if (isDeviceReady) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onFailure);
    } else {
        //here you could set an interval to check the value of `isDeviceReady` and then call the geo-location code when it is set to `true`
    }
});
```

Comment: but how do i only run that code for the #singleCompany 'page'?

Comment: If you want to go with the second option, you could use a global Deferred rather than boolean. That way you wouldn't have to poll.  But a simpler solution is to leave the geolocation on pageinit, and load the page out of onDeviceReady/wlCommonInit.  That way you know cordova is ready when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are using Worklight then putting your code or calling a function from inside the wlEnvInit or wlCommonInit function will do the trick.

Comment: You can put your code inside the Worklight init function. It is called only after the device is ready and the page is ready.